# How can I build mapbox-gl.js with Browserify?

Tags: browserify, mapbox-gl-js

If I git clone the repo (from [mapbox-gl.js repo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js)), how can I build my own standalone version of the files?

I just need the standalone mapbox-gl.js, like [this one](https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.14.3/mapbox-gl.js).

A simple `browserify js/mapbox-gl.js -o dist/mapbox-gl.js` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added a [section to the mapbox-gl-js readme](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js#creating-a-standalone-build) on this topic.

> #### Creating a Standalone Build
>
> A standalone build allows you to turn the contents of this repository
>   into `mapbox-gl.js` and `mapbox-gl.css` files that can be included on
>   an html page.
>
> To create a standalone build, run `bash npm run production`
>
> Once that command finishes, you will have a standalone build at
>   `dist/mapbox-gl.js` and `dist/mapbox-gl.css`

I hope that helps! Let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

To create standalone files, run `npm run build` in root of repo.